# Reference to a calendar object

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I need to reference an fullcalendar object – to change contents or options after intialisation - , but I always get the error message.

I first tried the javascript initialisation and then the jQuery version. I've tried "calendar.refech()" and "calendar.fullcalendar.refetch()" and "$.(#calendar)('refetchEvents')"

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    $(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            plugins: 
                [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ,'list'],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            locale: 'de',
            defaultDate: heute,
            {…}
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: 'load.php',
        })
    });
});

$('#calendar').getOption('locale');
```

The last line in code produces the errror: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Comment: fullCalendar v4 is not a jQuery plugin any longer. So any attempt to reference it via jQuery will fail. `calendar.getOption("locale")` should so the job. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Comment: Even if I define calendar without jQuery and try to reference it outside the init code, I get "Uncaught reference error: calendar is not defined" when trying to output console.log(calendar.getOption('locale'). Again: how can I reference my calendar object?

Comment: you need to make sure it's in scope wherever you want to use it. The same would be true of any JavaScript variable. The simplest way would be just to make `calendar` global. But if, like me, you prefer to avoid using globals then you could find another way to pass the object reference around in your code.

Comment: Sorry, still not working: myCalendar is global, but still "undefined". Have a look at the source: http://dev.umsicht.eu/stepKalender/fullcalendar-4/examples/selectable.php

Comment: `console.log(myCalendar.getOption('locale'));` is not inside the DOMContentLoaded callback. So it will execute before you initialise the calendar and populate the variable. Please understand that any JS directly inside a script block (but not inside any other function) will execute immediately when the script block loads. DOMContentLoaded event doesn't occur until the whole DOM has been loaded not just the script block, so that callback will execute later. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why is the getOption line out there by itself? What do you actually want to do with it in reality?

Comment: P.S. You can read about the DOMContentLoaded event here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in your code, calendarEl is initialized but never used.

Basically, you can initialize the main Calendar object out of eventListener DOMContentLoaded, and utilize it as global within that page like the following code:

```
var myCalendar;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var myCalendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: 
                [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ,'list'],
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            locale: 'de',
            defaultDate: heute,
            {…}
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: 'load.php'
    });

    myCalendar.render();
});
```

The initialization of Calendar object is provided in [this link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals).

Comment: Thank you, got it! Goal was to redraw an event after it has been inserted into the DB. The way to do this is "refetchevents". The locale-option was to see how referencing works, i think i can do it now: my function is within the DOMContentLoaded-init function and should work now. Thank you again!!

Comment: And if you want to work with multiple locales please have a look at this doc: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale. It has examples too

Comment: I accepted the answer 19 hours ago – or did I hit the wrong button (this was my first question ever)?

Comment: @StephanSelle - could you post the code that worked for you? I am trying to do the exact same thing. I initialise the calendar exactly as Khurram Ishaque but i am getting confused / lost / stumped as to how to reference the calendar at the end of my ajax insert code - the database entry works fine and I want to refresh the calendar without refreshing the page

Comment: @MelOncOlly: I left Calendar and did it on my own. I wrote a plain vanilla java script version for my own calendar, it works fine and I know where to go if I want to change it. If you are interested I can give you my code (only if you promise not to ask for my help ;-). regards stephan